# ¿Cómo devolver datos de tablas relacionadas con Linq to entities asp.net? (problemas codigo capa de negocios)

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

Me encuentro practicando Linq to Entities, (ASP.NET) para mostrar en un GridView datos de unas tablas desde la capa lógica a la capa de presentación.

Lo siguiente es mi diagrama de datos

[image: Diagrama de datos]

Las tablas que se encuentran encerradas en el recuadro rojo son las que deseo enlazar.

El problema es que cuando las enlazo por medio de Linq y las llamo al GridView no cargan datos de las tablas relacionadas.

Los datos que necesito cargar son :
**[Tablas] (Propiedades)** 
[atencionVehiculo] (PatenteVehiculo) 
[atencionVehiculo] (id) 
[atencionVehiculo] (nroMotor) 
[atencionVehiculo] (nroChasis) 
[MarcaVehiculo] (nombreMarca) 
[ModeloVehiculo] (nombreModelo) 
[Transmision] (tipoTransmision) 
[SelloVehiculo] (selllo)

A continuación el código de la capa de negocio, donde solo obtengo las claves foráneas de cada tabla:

```
    public string PatenteVehiculo { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int modeloId { get; set; }
    public int TransmisionId { get; private set; }
    public int nroMotor { get; set; }
    public string nroChasis { get; set; }
    public int SelloId { get; set; }
    public int marcaId { get; private set; }

    public List<ReimpresionCertificadoBL> GetAtencionVehiculoP(string patente)
    {           
            var atencionVehiculo = bd.atencionVehiculo
            .Include("AtencionVehiculo")
            .Where(c => c
            .PatenteVehiculo == patente)
            .Select(c => new ReimpresionCertificadoBL()
            {
                id = c.id,
                PatenteVehiculo = c.PatenteVehiculo,
                TransmisionId = c.transmisionId,
                nroChasis = c.nroChasis,
                nroMotor = c.nroMotor,
                marcaId = c.marcaId,
                modeloId = c.modeloId,
                SelloId = c.SelloId,



            });


            return atencionVehiculo.ToList();  
    }
```

La tabla en la capa de presentación, busca por patente

[image: Se los valores de la tabla atencionVehiculo]

Al no saber como  llamar los valores de las otras tablas solo imprimo claves foráneas. Deseo llamar los nombres de cada propiedad de cada tabla por medio de las claves foráneas que imprimo.

Anexo código GridView:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1">
        <Columns>
          <asp:BoundField DataField="PatenteVehiculo" HeaderText="PatenteVehiculo" SortExpression="PatenteVehiculo" />
          <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="id" SortExpression="id" />
          <asp:BoundField DataField="modeloId" HeaderText="modeloId" SortExpression="modeloId" />
          <asp:BoundField DataField="TransmisionId" HeaderText="TransmisionId" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="TransmisionId" />
           <asp:BoundField DataField="nroMotor" HeaderText="nroMotor" SortExpression="nroMotor" />
           <asp:BoundField DataField="nroChasis" HeaderText="nroChasis" SortExpression="nroChasis" />
           <asp:BoundField DataField="SelloId" HeaderText="SelloId" SortExpression="SelloId" />
           <asp:BoundField DataField="marcaId" HeaderText="marcaId" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="marcaId" />
        </Columns>
  </asp:GridView>

                                        <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectMethod="GetAtencionVehiculoP" TypeName="LogicaNegocios.Paginas.ReimpresionCertificadoBL">
                                            <SelectParameters>
                                                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtPatente" DefaultValue="PatenteVehiculo" Name="patente" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
                                            </SelectParameters>
                                        </asp:ObjectDataSource>

                                    </div>
```

Comment: podrias usar un join y hacer un objeto anonimo y eso lo pasas a tu gridview

Comment: no coloques una respuesta para hacer un comentario. Borra la respuesta y comentale en su respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solucionado:
Considerar que la clase se llama ReimpresionCertificadoBL

```
public class ReimpresionCertificadoBL<br/>
{
    //Conexion a la bd
    IdiaEntities bd = new IdiaEntities();

    public string marca { get; set; }
    public int nroAtencion { get; set; }
    public string patenteVehiculo { get; set; }
    public string modelo { get; set; }
    public string nroChasis { get; set; }
    public int nroMotor { get; set; }
    public string nombre { get; set; }
    public string aMaterno { get; set; }
    public string aPaterno { get; set; }

    public List<ReimpresionCertificadoBL> GetAtencionVehiculoP(string patente)
    {
        var atencioVehiculo = from
                              a in bd.atencionVehiculo
                              join ma in bd.MarcaVehiculo on a.marcaId equals ma.id
                              join mo in bd.ModeloVehiculo on a.modeloId equals mo.id
                              join se in bd.SelloVehiculo on a.SelloId equals se.id
                              join pr in bd.PropietarioVehiculo on a.propietarioId equals pr.id
                              join tm in bd.Transmision on a.transmisionId equals tm.id
                              join tc in bd.Traccion on a.traccionId equals tc.id
                              where a.PatenteVehiculo ==
                              patente
                              select new ReimpresionCertificadoBL()
                              {

                                  nroAtencion = a.id,
                                  nroChasis = a.nroChasis,
                                  nroMotor = a.nroMotor,
                                  patenteVehiculo = a.PatenteVehiculo,
                                  marca = ma.nombreMarca,
                                  modelo = mo.nombreModelo,
                                  nombre = pr.nombresPropietario,
                                  aMaterno = pr.propietarioApellidoMaterno,
                                  aPaterno = pr.propietarioApellidoPaterno

                              };
        return atencioVehiculo.ToList();
    }

}
```

Comment: @japv arriba esta la solución

Comment: Socio la solucion que yo te di funciona y es corta sin usar join innecesarios, el unico error que tenias es q no ponias las llaves cuando construias construias al objeto ReimpresionCertificadoBL en el select de la consulta, igualmente es bueno que tu mismo hayas solucionado el problema

Answer (score 1):

Podes hacer un join, y llamar a cada tabla y hacer su igualdad con el Id con que se vinculen, fijate que llamo a las tablas y le pongo un alias, luego con `new` creo un objeto anonimo o puedes hacer tu objeto en una clase. Como estan las clases cortadas en las imagenes no se si estan bien llamadas las clases en mi consulta pero es para que entiendas la idea.

```
 var atencionVehiculo = (from vehi in bd.atencionVehiculo
                        join respo in propietarioVehiculo on respo.PropietarioId equals vehi.Id
                        Where vehi.PatenteVehiculo == patente
                        Select new {
                                    id = vehi.id,
                                    Nombre = respo.NombresPropietario
                                   //llamar a todas las propiedades necesarias
                                   }).ToList();


        return atencionVehiculo.ToList();
```

Comment: Ya lo solucione amigo, arriba esta la solucion, gracias.

Comment: @LeonardoAntonioMolinasCarde no hay problema, lo que hiciste arriba es completar lo que te di, mi respuesta es para que entendieras que tenias que hacer con cada consulta, porque si tu sistema cambia una propiedad tu misma respuesta queda obsoleta.

Answer (score 0):

Pues aquí precisamente es donde está la magia de linq, al ser un lenguaje de consultas orientado a objetos puedes acceder a estos a través de la notación objeto.propiedad.otrapropiedad.algomas, Prueba esta consulta

```
var atencioVehiculo = from 
v in bd.AtencioVehiculo
where v.PatenteVehiculo == 
patente
select new ReimpresionCertificadoBL()
{
   v.id,
   v.PatenteVehiculo,
   v.NroChasis,
   v.NroMotor,
   Marca = v.MarcaVehiculo.NombreMarca,
   Modelo = v.ModeloVehiculo.NombreModelo,
   Sello = v.SelloVehiculo.NombreSello
}
```

En el modelo de objetos las tablas son tratadas como objetos, un ejemplo de lo que te decía antes, la propiedad Marca que seleccionas en tu consulta  pongo Marca = v.MarcaVehiculo.NombreMarca, así es como se accede a una tabla relacionada con otra a través de las propiedades de navegación, en este caso la propiedad de navegación es MarcaVehiculo, que representa la relación entre el objeto(tabla) vehículo y marca, y NombreMarca es el nombre del campo en la Tabla Marca al cual accedes para obtener precisamente la marca del vehículo, yo le puse NombreMarca, en tu modelo puede tener otro nombre

Nota: en el select me faltó poner la transmisión, es lo mismo que con marca.

Ahora bien que sucede si en
v.MarcaVehiculo.NombreMarca, MarcaVehiculo es null, en otras palabras que sucede si el vehículo no tiene una marca, pues te dará tremendismo error, pues estas tratando de acceder a la propiedad de un objeto que no existe, esto puedes solucionarlo de la siguiente manera

```
Marca = (v.MarcaVehiculo != null) ?
v.MarcaVehiculo.NombreMarca :
"Sin Marca",
```

Esto quiere decir que si MarcaVehiculo no es nulo entonces se mostrará la marca del vehículo, en caso contrario se mostrará el texto "Sin Marca", esto es aplicable también al campo Modelo, y a las otras relaciones entre tablas.

Usar linq tiene muchas ventajas ya que al ser un lenguaje de consulta orientado a objetos, puedes utilizar características propias de estas como la herencia y el polimorfismo, además de que las consultas son más legibles y en caso de haber algún error este es detectado en tiempo de compilación

Comment: Hola, te comento que presento el mismo problema, en síntesis la solución que me entregas es el mismo problema en el que me encontraba :(

Comment: Acabo de agregar una captura de pantalla

Comment: Aqui el error te da pq no pones las llaves cuando construyes el objeto ReimpresionCertificadoBL deberias poner select new ReimpresionCertificadoBL(){...} fijate bien @LeonardoAntonioMolinasCarde